# Why is Goal-directed reasoning and heuristic search hard to combine?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

In Artificial Intelligence - A Modern Approach 3rd Edition, I came across an interesting quote stating:

"As yet there is no good understanding of how to combine the two kinds of algorithms [Goal directed reasoning / planning and heuristic search] into a robust and efficient system" (Russel pg 189)

Why is this so? Why is it hard to combine goal oriented planning with a heuristic search? Wouldn't reinforcement learning solve this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term “Goal directed reasoning” was used in the 1980s for a backtracking search technique. Sometimes it was called backward reasoning or top-down search, which means all the same. It describes the working of the algorithm in traversing the state space. Or to be more specific: it describes the order in which the states in the graph are visited. In newer literature this aspect of a planner is no longer explained in detail, because a graph search algorithm is no big thing. It means simply to put the nodes on a stack and traverse them.

In contrast, the term “heuristic search” means to replace a brute-force solver with a knowledge based approach. Heuristic search is equal to not traverse a graph, but find a domain-specific strategy which leaves out most part of the graph. And indeed, it is hard to combine backtracking with heuristics, this approach would be called grounding. If a grounded problem is available, it is possible to use a backtracking solver on a knowledge-based problem. This is the strategy utilized in modern PDDL planners which are first describe the domain in a symbolic PDDL notation (which is knowledge based) and using then a fast solver to search in the state space.